# Dropdown menu's fighting with each other

Tags: css, theme-twenty-ten

I'm sure there's a simple CSS answer to this that I'm not seeing :(

http://www.glennduxbury-inspections.com/litb/

On my navigation menu if you hover over a sub menu item, and then slowly move your mouse to the right, it will switch to the next items sub menu. I don't want this to happen especially for the "services" dropdown, because it has a 3rd tier menu I can't even hover over.

I've tried throwing z-index's on the sub menu, and all the items under the sub menu. Nothing I do seems to work, I'm stumped at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that though your sub menu is set to `opacity: 0`, its still displaying, just transparent.  So when you hover any area where a submenu is present, you're triggering `#access ul li:hover` which sets the opacity of the submenu with `#access ul li:hover > ul`.  Try setting adding `visibility: hidden` to `#access ul ul`.  Then add `visibility: visible` to `#access ul li:hover > ul`.  This will allow you to keep the opacity transition.

Comment: Can I still have the effect where the menu fades in if I'm not using opacity? That was the only reason I was using opacity and not just display.

Comment: Good point.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I think it is visibility:hidden, but adding that totally worked and preserved the hover effect with opacity. I will remember to use visibility instead of display from now on :)

Comment: You're right.  I updated.